# Adding the isParallel annotation to existing test class

Tags: apex, unit-test, winter18

Currently, I have a test class defined as follows:

```
@isTest(seeAllData=false)
public with sharing class UnitTest {
//Test class
}
```

With the introduction of the Winter '18 release, I would like to also use the `@isTest(isParallel=true)` annotation.

I've tried including it in the same tag, separated by a comma as follows: `@isTest(seeAllData=false, isParallel=true` and as a brand new annotation under the existing one:

```
@isTest(seeAllData=false)
@isTest(isParallel=true)
public with sharing class UnitTest {
//Test class
}
```

Can anyone point me to the correct format, or is it impossible to use multiple annotations simultaneously?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply give both parameters with a space:

```
@isTest(isParallel=true seeAllData=false)
```

Note that you don't need to specify seeAllData=false, as that is the default behavior, but you might need to know this for other annotations in the future.

Comment: I was actually trying to do the very same thing, using comma for seperating attributes in the annoation but I gave up thinking that the attributes were mutally exclusive or something. Did not realize the separator was a space. Is this documented anywhere? Any ideas why Salesforce chose to use a space instead of a comma for seperating attributes? Just seems confusing, I assumed it would be similar to Java but I guess that's my fault for assuming.

Comment: @AlanMorey I don't think it's *explicitly* documented anywhere, but there's an example of it in [InvocableMethod](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_InvocableMethod.htm). Maybe some documentation feedback would be appropriate.